# summation of columns of a data.frame based on ifelse conditions in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, tidyverse

I want to add Column `A` and `X` based on the `conditions` that `if` the result is `greater than zero`, use the summation result `otherwise` make it `zero`. Here is my code so far

```
library(tidyverse)
library(set.seed(1500)
FakeData <- data.frame(A = runif(20,-5,20), X = runif(20,0,22))

FakeData$sum <- if (sum(FakeData$A+FakeData$X) < 0){
  0
} else {
  sum(FakeData$A+FakeData$X
}
```

Comment: my bad- that was a mistake. thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `pmax` in `base R`.  It should be faster

```
FakeData$Sum <- with(FakeData, pmax(0, A + X))
```

---

The `if/else` is not vectorized.  Instead use `ifelse`

```
FakeData$Sum <- with(FakeData, ifelse(A + X < 0, 0, A + X))
```